# No se como enviar la ruta de un upload file de PHP a mysqli por medio de crud

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que tengo un código que me permite subir archivos de forma automática solo con cargarlos al input file y este me envía la ruta a la base de datos en MySQL. El problema esta en que tengo un datatable que me muestra otros resultado, lo que quiero es implementar el código pasado para adjuntar archivos PDF pero que estos estén relacionados con un ID.

Este es mi index.php, esto esta dentro de un modal, lo digo por si las moscas-

```
            <input type="text" hidden="" id="id_ReferenciasU" name="id_ReferenciasU">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Subir archivo</label>
            <center><input type="file"  id="fileToUpload" onchange="upload_image();"></center>
            <p class="help-block">Seleccion un archivo.</p>
            <div class="upload-msg"></div><!--Para mostrar la respuesta del archivo llamado via ajax -->                
            </div>         
            </form>
```

Como pueden ver solo tengo 2 inputs, uno hidden para que me ayude con la identificación del ID del paciente en cuestión y al momento de seleccionar el input file se va a una función llamada upload_image que hace que se suban las imágenes automáticamente.

Este es mi script en js:

```
<script>
function upload_image(){//Funcion encargada de enviar el archivo via AJAX
            $(".upload-msg").text('Cargando...');
            var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("fileToUpload")
            var file = inputFileImage.files[0];
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('fileToUpload',file, id_Ref);
            
            
                        
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",        
                type: "POST",             
                data: data,               
                contentType: false,       
                cache: false,            
                success: function(data)   
                {
                    $(".upload-msg").html(data);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".alert-dismissible").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    }); }, 5000);
                }
            });
            
        }
```

En javascript intente llamando personalmente el id que esta como hidden para luego compararlo con el id_ref que esta en la base de datos pero siempre llegaba con valor a 0 y nunca pude compararlo.
Y este mi archivo upload.php.

```
<?php require_once "../clases/conexion.php";
$obj= new conectar(); $conexion=$obj->conexion();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"])){
$target_dir = "upload/";
$carpeta=$target_dir;
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
} 
$target_file = $carpeta.(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $errors[]= "El archivo es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $errors[]= "El archivo no es una imagen.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $errors[]="Lo sentimos, archivo ya existe.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5242808) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, el archivo es demasiado grande.  Tamaño máximo admitido: 5 MB";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "pdf" ) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, sólo se permiten archivos PDF.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, tu archivo no fue subido.";

} else {
    if (mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into files(url) Values ('$target_file')")){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       $messages[]= var_dump($id_Ref);     
    } else {
       $errors[]= "Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.";
    }}
}
 

?>
```

Realmente este codigo php es mas validaciones que cualquier otra cosa, tambien tengo una tabla php que es la que comentaba al comienzo que es la que esta relacionando casi la mayoria de datos y en donde esta el boton del modal del input file.
Espero haberme dado a entender, de antemano, gracias.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que haces, al menos yo. Si te fijas, pones esto: `<input type="text" hidden="" id="id_ReferenciasU" name="id_ReferenciasU">` que no tiene ni **value** y que el **type** deberia ser **hidden** y no **text** (y ese atributo `hidden=` lo puedes borrar). Y por otro lado, usas $id_Ref en el PHP sin haberlo definido antes, y en el javascript tambien usas esto: `data.append('fileToUpload',file, id_Ref);` donde el `id_Ref` que aparece tampoco viene de ninguna parte y no se a que nombre de archivo se corresponderia.

Comment: @masterguru, entiendo lo que me dices, iré a aplicarlo. En cuanto al input, solo lo transformo en type Hidden y ya esta, cierto? el resto lo dejo como esta (Quitando el hidden="", evidentemente y sin colocarle value?).

Comment: @masterguru, para el data.append le coloque el siguiente codigo `var id_Ref = document.getElementById("id_ReferenciasU");` Con eso quedaria definido el id_Ref, cierto? Referente al input lo deje de esta manera `<input type="hidden" id="id_ReferenciasU" name="id_ReferenciasU" >` De igual manera ya con eso quedaria bien, correcto?

Comment: El hidden se escribe así:  `type="hidden"` y en cuanto al **value**, un input con solo un **name** e **id** y sin **value** no se para que lo quieres.  Entiendo que el `value=` debe ser el valor de ese `id_ReferenciasU` que luego quieres usar en el el PHP como `$id_Ref`

Comment: @masterguru, vale vale ire a intentar con todo esto nuevo a ver. Porque el problema que tenia era que el input hidden como lo tenia anteriormente, no recibia ningun valor al momento del seleccionar el boton del modal.

Comment: Tampoco tengo muy claro para que quieres ponerle el tercer parámetro al `append`. El tercer parámetro indica un nombre de archivo en modo texto y si haces la asignación `var id_Ref = document.getElementById("id_ReferenciasU");` entonces `id_Ref` pasa a ser un objeto y no un string, y seguramente petará.  Yo quizas  quitaria ese tercer parámetro y pondria otro append más así: `data.append('id_Ref', document.getElementById("id_ReferenciasU").value );`  habiendo puesto antes un **value** a ese input con el valor que tenga ese id, claro.

Comment: Se supone que si el `input` es de tipo `hidden` el usuario no podrá verlo, no podrá modificarlo, de lo que se deduce que ese archivo **está destinado a tener un nombre fijo**, entonces, ¿para que enrollarse con lo del input de tipo `hidden`? ¿por qué no asignas el nombre directamente, dado que será un nombre fijo? Por otro lado, cuando trabajas con FormData en jQuery conviene que añadas este parámetro: `processData: false,` para evitar que los datos se conviertan en un query string.